# Font missing in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: fonts

I just installed Elemetary OS 5.0 Juno.

Roboto Medium is listed in the **Fonts** application, but this font is not available in LibreOffice Writer! Why?

Answer (score 0):

Well... nice to see i'm not the only one having this problem. I installed MS fonts (msttcorefonts) and Calibri is not showing up. Pitty it had to be the most used font for MS Office docs...
Apparently Support for Type 1 fonts has been removed. Not sure if this interferes directly with that particular font, but you can try to paste a copy of the font to /usr/share/fonts.

I'll try to see if it works when i have the time.

Comment: Here is some good news. Remove all package `fonts-roboto` and any other automatically installed roboto fonts, and use `fonts-roboto-fontface`. That shows up almost everywhere, except Firefox! Thats fixes issue with Roboto. I'm sure another package will solve your MS font issue! Keep looking!